# Deploy Build Servers toolchain using Puppet, Chef or Ansible

Tags: configuration, msbuild, chef-infra, puppet, toolchain

We have this issue. 
We want to automate the deployment of our Continuous Delivery Build Server Tool chain using a Configuration Management tool such us Puppet, Chef or Ansible.

More precisely we have a bunch of tools (e.g. nuget, NUnit, MSBuild etc) that we use in our Continuous Delivery infrastructure. These tools are deployed to Several Build Servers. Maintaining the configuration of them is time consuming and error prone (i.e. different configuration in different Server resulting is error when building our solution using the Continuous Delivery tools).

We want to automate the maintenance of their configurations and we were thinking to use the Configuration Management tools such us Puppet, Chef or Ansible.

The question is: Are these the right tools for achieving the Configuration Management of our Build Server toolchain?

Anyone having experienced the same issue and how do you solve it?

Thanks in Advance

Alberto

Comment: You should also consider the platform onto which you are deploying and what steps you can avoid automating. By way of example, I spent a great deal of time automating Jenkins build configuration on AWS, only to realize it was simpler and less error-prone to store build data on a regularly snapshotted EBS volume.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. All of these 3 can help you with that. Which one is better is highly opinion-based.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: This is a valid answer to what the OP wrote after *"The question is"*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, convergent configuration management tools such as the ones you listed are a widely used and powerful way to manage servers. The question is still very vague so that's about the best I can say.